# Styled Anchor tags( <a> ) disappear after being clicked on IE 8 and lower

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Good day, to stackoverflow community. I have run into a bug with regard to html, css and Internet Explorer.

Styled  tags are used as a filter of sorts. They look and act like buttons, the functionality works fine on Chrome and Mozilla but graphical errors appear once these  tags are clicked on IE.

On IE9 the background div leaks into the images of the styled tags (after much testing I found that this was caused by the Layout values offset changing once the item has been clicked.)

On IE8 and IE7 the tags simply disappear completely once clicked, It will run the onclick process and finnish running it (we change the class="" attribute to change appearance on click and hover according to the css) but after that completes it simply removes the visual element completely on the front end (according to layout the width and height are both changed to 0 and the margin values are changed to auto). P.S. only the clicked element is affected.

2  tag examples of the affected elements.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <link href="styles/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>   
    <body>
       <a id="virginActiveTag" class="vaOff" href="#"     onclick="tagClick('virginActiveTag')"></a>
       <a id="laFitnessTag" class="lafOn" href="#"     onclick="tagClick('laFitnessTag')"></a>  
    </body>
 </html>
```

Example of styling for one of the elements.

```
 a.vaOn:link {margin:0 10px 10px 0px;display:inline-block;width:200px;height:95px;background:#fff url(../images/logos_va_on.gif) no-repeat 0 -8px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #5c822a;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#5c822a;box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #5c822a;}
 a.vaOff:link {margin:0 10px 10px 0px;display:inline-block;width:200px;height:95px;background:#fff url(../images/logos_va_on.gif) no-repeat 0 -110px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;}
 a.vaOff:hover {background:#fffffe url(../images/logos_va_on.gif) no-repeat 0 -8px;}
```

Link to finalized site: http://pru-partnerfinder.appspot.com/

I believe that it has something to do with the hasLayout property that IE allocates to certain elements. But am not completely sure. I have tried to physically hard code the elements back to their original sizes in the onclick event but it does not accept the new values and only the margin in ie8 gets set properly.

Thanks for any help beforehand. I'm simply at stumped, could anyone assist?

Comment: I have looked at your code, but, unfortunately I'm unable to understand what you want to do!!
Is it something like "Clicking on the particular box (the small images in your case) highlights a shadow around it ?" I need more info regarding this. Plz share....

Comment: If you go to the public domain site : http://pru-partnerfinder.appspot.com/ on chrome or mozilla you can see the functionality of the tags (the logos) as they are supposed to work. The idea is you select which partners you want to find (disable or enable the tags and they act as filters) and then input your address and click search and all partners within a certain distance are displayed on a google map canvas. When you click on the tags the gif file (this gif file contains two logos) shifts its viewport according to the tag class by altering the background position in the style.

Comment: This functionality still works in IE but it seems that IE's Layout manager changes the values(height, weight, margin) of the tags after the onclick event completes. Causing graphical bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HasLayout is gone in IE8 and above (but you can trigger it by putting IE into Quirks Mode or IE7 compat or whatever...): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405844(v=vs.85).aspx

Are you triggering Quirks Mode or similar?

Can you fix your problem if you style a straight element instead of a pseudo-class? IE *was* rather famous for getting itchy about changing display states between pseudo-classes. Besides, once an anchor's been clicked, it's not :link anymore, it's :visited, and styling the element itself naturally extends to :link, :visited etc. Then :hover, :active and :focus only need to override "a".

```
a.vaOn, a.vaOff {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0; 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 95px;
  background: #fff url(../images/logos_va_on.gif) no-repeat 0 -8px;
  ...etc...
}
a.vaOff {
  background-position: 0 -110px;
}
```

This sets a base on the elements themselves: display state (inline-block, for whatever that's worth in IE7), width and height.  If IE6 and absolute positioning were involved then you'd have to just suck it up and re-state the heights again on :hover, but you didn't mention that one.

```
a.vaOff:hover, a.vaOff:focus {
  background-position: 0 -8px;
}
```

What I'm saying is, at least in older IE (6, 7) where you set your dimensions and display states mattered, so if you try this style of setup, does the problem go away or change?

IE8 and 9 make this interesting, because neither had Layout anymore and neither were quite so picky about where you stated display states.

Comment: You my friend are a king thank you soo much you hit it right on the nail. I can't upvote(not enough rep). None the less thank you soo much. Can't believe the solution was so simple. as you suggested removing the ":link" and chaning it to a straight element.